# The following function is only continuous at one point. Is it differentiable at that point?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, proof-verification, continuity, alternative-proof

$h(x) = 0, x ∈ \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$

$h(x) = x^2, x ∈ \mathbb{Q}$

Here is my proof:

$\forall x ∈ \mathbb{Q}, \lim_{x\to 0} x^2 = 0$
$\forall x ∈ \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}, \lim_{x\to 0} 0 = 0$

So the function is continuous at x=0, and h(0)=0

$\forall x ∈ \mathbb{Q}, \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{h(x)-h(0)}{x-0} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x^2}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0} x = 0$

$\forall x ∈ \mathbb{Q}, \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{h(x)-h(0)}{x-0} =  \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{0}{x} = 0$

Hence h is differentiable at that point.

Comment: Right now you're only considering rational and irrational sequences, but you need to check it for all real sequences. This is easily done by estimating the quotient by your first case.

Comment: @ThePhenotype It is enough to compute the limit along two disjoint subsets, which union is the reals. That proof is correct. Prove it as an exercise, if $A,B$ are disjoint sets that accumulate at $a$, $A\cup B$ contains a neighborhood of $a$, and $\lim_{A\ni x\to a}f(x)=L$ and $\lim_{B\ni x\to a}f(x)=L$, then $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L$. His only problem is the notation.

Comment: @minghan That's indeed an interesting exercise to note and apply here.

Comment: @chilliefiber That argument is correct, using or proving first the property in my comment above. The notation $\forall x\in\mathbb{Q}\lim_{x\to 0}$ is not adequate. The variable $x$ in $\lim_{x\to 0}$ is already quantified with a $\forall$ inside the definition of limit. You could write $\lim_{x\to 0, x\in\mathbb{Q}}$ or something alike such that people understand what you wanted to say.

Comment: There is a version of the squeeze theorem for differentiable functions. When $g \le f \le h$ in the neighbourhood of a point $a$ and $g$ and $h$ are differentiable at $a$, then their derivatives agree, and $f'(a)$ exists and is equal to $a$. In this case, we have $0 \le f(x) \le x^2$, so the derivative must be $0$.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make sense to write that $(\forall x\in\mathbb{Q}):\lim_{x\to0}\frac{h(x)-h(0)}{x-0}=0$. You can prove that $h$ is differentiable at $0$ by noticing that$$(\forall x\in\mathbb{R}):\left|\frac{h(x)-h(0)}x\right|\leqslant|x|,$$from which it follows that $h'(0)=0$.